# Drools on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7, drools

I'm new to drools so this question might be based on opinion. I've used drools6.5 in our Standalone Java Applications, but would now like to add it to our existing /webapps on Tomcat7(JDK8). The webapps are simple jsp/servlet/html based (mostly hand coded - without Spring).

Are there any examples out there that would help me get Drools6.5 working on our Tomcat/webapps? I've tried creating the following structure hoping it would work.

`webapps/
     WEB-INF/
        |--classes/all_my_classes.class
     META-INF/
        |--maven
              |---pom.properties
        |--kmodule.xml
  |--rules/myrule.drl`

But the code generated a null pointer exception when kSession.insert() is called.

```
DroolsPojoIn message = new DroolsPojoIn();
//## message setters.
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
kSession.insert(message);  //Generated NullPointerException.
```

This same code and structure works well in the standalone Apps.

Thanks & Best Regards
Shawn

Comment: If the stack dump starts at this line, kSession is null and the "same code" cannot have worked otherwise. How do you create this object?

Comment: I just added the sample code. The kSession is initialized in the previous lines.. But it still generates a NullPointer..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the following URL

[Loading and updating rules from a database in Drools 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243805/loading-and-updating-rules-from-a-database-in-drools-6)

First I deleted the META-INF folder (It was not necessary). Then I declared the main 3 class variables outside any functions. It was easier for us manually load the drools files through /paths than configure environments.

```
KieServices ks = null;
KieContainer kContainer;
KieSession kSession;
```

Then I added the following code to the servlet `public void init()` function.

```
ks = KieServices.Factory.get();         
/* File System Handler */
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
kfs.write("/data/rules/lesson01.drl", "/data/rules/sample02.drl"); 
KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
  System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
        throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
  }
kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
KieBase kieBase = kContainer.getKieBase();
kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
```

In the `public void doGet()` I fired the rules.

```
DroolsPojo message = new DroolsPojo(); /*My Simple Pojo object*/
message.setMessage("Marketing Strategy");
message.setStatus(DroolsPojo.MARKET);
kSession.insert(message);
kSession.fireAllRules();
```

If there's a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Don't ask questions in answers. And it's unclear why this fixes the NPE.